# Bitlocker Discovery Scan across network csv does not return data Powershell

Tags: powershell

This is the code auditor provided to us to check Pre-Audit if it is working and I am wondering
if permissions are needed to perform the proper script, but I already performed the script on an administrator console but to no luck, the CSV file being generated has no data inside so I am checking what is the problem here.

```
   REQUIREMENTS
    Active Directory module
    WinRM enabled on target machines (for WMI)
    Local administrator on target machines

    NB. Some WMI scans do not work on all operating systems (particularly older ones)

.AUDIT CRITERIA
    Complete a discovery scan of Bitlocker statuses

    Make a note of the following exceptions
        - Where the protection status is off
        - Where the encryption status is NOT 'FullyEncrypted'
```

```
    $Log = "C:\temp\Audit\$Domain Bitlocker Status $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"

    $Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -NOTLIKE "*server*" -AND Enabled -eq $TRUE} -Property Name
    $Computers = Get-Random -InputObject $Computers -Count 100

    $DriveType = "3"
    $DriveLetter = "C:"
    $obj=@()
    $Data = @()

    $OnCount = 0
    $UnknownCount = 0
    $OffCount = 0

    foreach ($Computer in $Computers.name) {

        try{
            write-host "Working on $Computer"

            $LocalDrives = Get-CimInstance -Namespace 'root\CIMV2' -ClassName 'CIM_LogicalDisk' -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction 'stop' | `
                Where-Object -Property 'DriveType' -in $DriveType
            $ComputerCount++

            Get-CimInstance  -Namespace 'root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption' -ClassName 'Win32_EncryptableVolume' -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction 'stop' | `
                Where-Object -Property 'DriveLetter' -in $($LocalDrives.DeviceID) | `
                ForEach-Object {

                #  Get the drive type
                $GetDriveType = $($LocalDrives | Where-Object -Property 'DeviceID' -eq $($_.DriveLetter)) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'DriveType'

                #  Create the Result Props and make the ProtectionStatus more report friendly
                $ResultProps = [ordered]@{
                    'Drive'            = $($_.DriveLetter)
                    'ProtectionStatus' = $(
                        Switch ($_.ProtectionStatus) {
                            0 { 'OFF' }
                            1 { 'ON' }
                            2 { 'UNKNOWN' }
                        }
                    )
                    'EncryptionStatus' = $(
                        Switch ($_.ConversionStatus) {
                            0 { 'FullyDecrypted' }
                            1 { 'FullyEncrypted' }
                            2 { 'EncryptionInProgress' }
                            3 { 'DecryptionInProgress' }
                            4 { 'EncryptionPaused' }
                            5 { 'DecryptionPaused' }
                        }
                    )
                    'DriveType' = $GetDriveType
                }

                $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer" -Value $Computer
                $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Drive" -Value $ResultProps.Drive
                $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Type" -Value $ResultProps.DriveType
                $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Protection" -Value $ResultProps.ProtectionStatus
                $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Encryption" -Value $ResultProps.EncryptionStatus

                $Data += $obj

                $DriveCount++
                if ($ResultProps.ProtectionStatus -eq 'OFF'){
                    $OffCount++
                }
                elseif ($ResultProps.ProtectionStatus -eq 'ON'){
                    $OnCount++
                }
                elseif ($ResultProps.ProtectionStatus -eq 'UNKNOWN'){
                    $UnknownCount++
                }
            }
        }

        Catch {
            write-host "WARNING: $Computer not accessible" -foregroundcolor yellow
        }
    }

    $Data | sort-object -property Computer,Drive | Export-Csv $Log -notype

    write-host ""
    write-host "There were $DriveCount drives listed from $ComputerCount computers"
    write-host "Protection is on: $OnCount"
    write-host "Protection is unknown: $UnknownCount" -foregroundcolor yellow
    write-host "Protection is off: $OffCount" -foregroundcolor red
```

Comment: do you see any output from the `Write-Host` calls?

Comment: I only see Example Computer not accessible most of the time

Comment: that means your `try/catch` is working ... but you are not passing out the actual error. try adding code to your `catch` that lists the error. i _think_ you do that by outputting the `$_` in the  catch.

Comment: tried different scripts regarding this figuring out if it might be something blocking the said powershell script or policy still not returning errors just no data

Comment: you said that this section >>> `Catch {write-host "WARNING: $Computer not accessible" -foregroundcolor yellow}` <<< is producing output. that ONLY runs if there is an error. have you tried adding `$_` to your catch block? have you tried looking at the most recent error in `$Error[0]`? i cannot think of any other ideas ... and cannot test your code since i have only one system and am not willing to fiddle with bitlocker on it.

Comment: Added the Error script and produced an error so if I am mistaken WinRM needs to be enabled on the target machines so I am in the process of requesting this.
will also try the script if I can on a single machine with WinRM enabled see if that is the case

Comment: hah! now  you know why hiding errors is unwise ... [*grin*] i presumed you had WinRM enabled - sorry for not asking about that one. it is a pretty common missed step.